# Links in company statements are hard to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, user-interface, design

This is from http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/fog-creek-software:

[image]

The blue links on a dark gray background do not have enough contrast to be readable.  A different color for the text would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. We'll look into it.

---

**UPDATE**
This issue has been resolved and the changes for this will go out with our next push to production. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Knock knock. :)